# creating a touch slider

Tags: jquery, css, touch

I'm trying to get my slider to work on a touch screen. The user must be able to swipe the images. I need it to work on tablets and phones. I tried to use $(".portfolio-overlay").swipe but that didn't work and I don't know if I did something wrong.

html

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
<div class="slider">
    <div class="portfolio-overlay">
        <ul class="images">
            <li>
                <img width="704px" class="portfolio-active portfolio-single" src="http://s25.postimg.org/keaisiflb/mini_brown_fairy.jpg">
            </li>
            <li>
                <img width="704px" class="portfolio-inactive portfolio-single" src="http://s25.postimg.org/xwhf4srqn/mini_blue_fairy.jpg">
            </li>
            <li>
                <img width="704px" class="portfolio-inactive portfolio-single" src="http://s25.postimg.org/smcgdi7hr/mini_purple_fairy.jpg">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="triggers">
    <li>
        <img src="images/border-box.png">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/border-box.png">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/border-box.png">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/border-box.png">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/border-box.png">
    </li>
</ul>
```

css

```
.slider {
float: left;
height: 465px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 0;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
width: 704px;
}
.images {
position:relative;
top:0px;
left:0px;
height:2660px;
}
.images li {
float:left;
position:relative;
top:0px;
left:0px;
}
.triggers {
left: 31.2%;
position: absolute;
top: 76.3%;
}
.triggers li {
float: left;
list-style: none outside none;
}
.triggers .selected {
background: url("../images/white-box.png") no-repeat scroll 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.swipe-for-more {
left: 24.3%;
position: absolute;
top: 76.3%;
}
.control {
position:absolute;
top: 380px;
color:#fff;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

jquery

```
    var triggers = $('.triggers li');
var images = $('.images li');
var lastElem = triggers.length - 1;
var slider = $('.slider .images');
var imgWidth = images.width();
var target;

triggers.first().addClass('selected');
slider.css('width', imgWidth * (lastElem + 1) + 'px');

function sliderResponse(target) {
    slider.stop(true, false).animate({
        'left': '-' + imgWidth * target + 'px'
    }, 300);
    triggers.removeClass('selected').eq(target).addClass('selected');
}

triggers.click(function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        target = $(this).index();
        sliderResponse(target);
        resetTiming();
    }
});
$('.next').click(function () {
    target = $('.triggers .selected').index();
    target === lastElem ? target = 0 : target = target + 1;
    sliderResponse(target);
    resetTiming();
});
$('.prev').click(function () {
    target = $('.triggers .selected').index();
    lastElem = triggers.length - 1;
    target === 0 ? target = lastElem : target = target - 1;
    sliderResponse(target);
    resetTiming();
});

function sliderTiming() {
    target = $('.triggers .selected').index();
    target === lastElem ? target = 0 : target = target + 1;
    sliderResponse(target);
}
var timingRun = setInterval(function () {
    sliderTiming();
}, 5000);

function resetTiming() {
    clearInterval(timingRun);
    timingRun = setInterval(function () {
        sliderTiming();
    }, 5000);
}

$(".portfolio-overlay").swipe({

    swipe: function (event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
        if ($(".portfolio-single").length < 1) return false;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        directionVAR = direction;
        if (direction == "left") {
            var bannerMove = $(".portfolio-active").index() + 1
            if ($(".portfolio-active").index() == ($(".portfolio-single").length - 1)) {

                bannerMove = 0;
            }
            rotateBanners(bannerMove);
        } else if (direction == "right") {
            rotateBanners(($(".portfolio-active").index() - 1));
        }
    },
    threshold: 0

});
```

Here is my jsfiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8e5rX/1/)

Comment: Would you be able to upload the images being used in your code, and then update the links in your fiddle accordingly? It would make it much easier to visualize what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: here is the updated jsfiddle: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8e5rX/2/) I don't want to add the proper images as the website is for someone else

Answer (score 0):

Maybe or maybe not what you need, but I use iScroll for touch swipes. It can be setup for vertical or horizontal scrolling, snap to points, etc. It's very flexible and very customizable. Easy to setup, too.

http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

or

http://iscrolljs.com

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what i need